# Creating a Function that produces a Function Scheme/DrRacket

Tags: function, scheme, structure, racket

I'm working on a function that takes in a list of structures and then using that list of structures produces a function that processes a list of symbols into a number. Each structure is made up of a symbol, that will be in the second list consumed, and a number. This function produced has to turn the list of symbols into a number by assigning each symbol a value based on the previous structures. Using abstract list functions btw.

```
    Example: ((function (list (make-value 'value1 10) (make-value 'value2 20)))
              (list 'value1 'value2 'nothing 'value1)) would produced 40.
```

Heres my code but it only works for specific cases.

```
 (define (function lst)
   (lambda (x) (foldr + 0 (map (lambda (x) 
                           (cond
                             [(equal? x (value-name(first lst)))(value-value (first  lst))]
                             [else (value-value (second lst))]))

                             (filter (lambda (x) (member? x (map value-name lst)))x)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a homework. Basic shape of your solution is ok. I think the reason you have a problem here is that there is no decomposition in your code so it's easy to get lost in parentheses.

Let's start with your idea of `fold`-ing with `+` over list of integers as a last step of computation.

For this subtask you have:

1) a list of (name, value) pairs 
2) a list of names

and you need to get a list of values. Write a separate function which does exactly that and use it. Like this

```
(define (function lst)
   (lambda (x) (foldr + 
                      0 
                      (to-values x lst)))

(define (to-values names names-to-values)
   (map (lambda (name) 
            (to-value name names-to-values))))

(define (to-value n ns-to-vs)
     ...)
```

Here we `map` over the `names` with another little function. It will lookup the `n` value in `ns-to-vs` and return it or 0 if there is no one.

Comment: How do I write that last function, I'm still running into my same issue

Comment: Write one then, it's easy. You can use your functions, right?

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches for solving the problem with `foldr`, it'd be interesting to study and understand both of them. The first one, attempted in the question, is to first produce a list with all the values and let `foldr` take care of adding them. It can be implemented in a simpler way like this:

```
(define (function lst)
  (lambda (x)
    (foldr +
           0
           (map (lambda (e)
                  (cond ((assoc e lst) => value-value)
                        (else 0)))
                x))))
```

Alternatively: maybe using `foldr` is overkill, applying `+` is simpler:

```
(define (function lst)
  (lambda (x)
    (apply +
           (map (lambda (e)
                  (cond ((assoc e lst) => value-value)
                        (else 0)))
                x))))
```

In the second approach we take the input list "as is" and let `foldr`'s `lambda` perform the addition logic. This is more efficient than the first approach using `foldr`, because there's no need to create an intermediate list - the one generated by `map` in the first version:

```
(define (function lst)
  (lambda (x)
    (foldr (lambda (e a)
             (cond ((assoc e lst) => (lambda (p) (+ a (value-value p))))
                   (else a)))
           0
           x)))
```

In both approaches I'm using [`assoc`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._assoc%29%29) for finding the element in the list; it's easy to implement as a helper function if you're not allowed to use it or if it doesn't work  for the values created with `make-value`: `assoc` takes a list of name-value pairs and returns the first pair with the given name. The `=>` syntax of `cond` passes the pair returned by `assoc` to a `lambda`'s parameter and executes it.

And because you're using Racket, there's a bit of syntactic sugar that can be used for returning a function from another function, try this equivalent code, for simplicity's sake:

```
(define ((function lst) x)
  (foldr +
         0
         (map (lambda (e)
                (cond ((assoc e lst) => value-value)
                      (else 0)))
              x)))
```

Or this:

```
(define ((function lst) x)
  (foldr (lambda (e a)
           (cond ((assoc e lst) => (lambda (p) (+ a (value-value p))))
                 (else a)))
         0
         x))
```

Anyway, the result is as expected:

```
((function (list (make-value 'value1 10) (make-value 'value2 20)))
 (list 'value1 'value2 'nothing 'value1))
=> 40
```